# Accessing a file which is at the root of the project directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to refer to an XML file called BaseBindings.xml which is in the root of my project  from within the app.config file of my C# application.

This file contains the necessary ninject bindings which are necessary for the application to load up. I have trying several ways to access from within the app.config file but haven't had success yet.

These are the few ways I tried setting the path within the app.config.

```
 <add key="defaultFile" value=".\BaseBindings.xml" />
 <add key="defaultFile" value="..\BaseBindings.xml" />
```

[image: Project structure]

Could somebody guide me where  i am going wrong ?

Comment: Why you are reposting?

Comment: @selvin I have just tried to make my question clear ? Is there any issue ? I thought the previous post didn't have sufficient information. I think you should appreciate that I have tried to rephrase it than discourage

Comment: Please let me know what you have not understood in the post

Comment: It seems like a test project.. Then you should provide the path to the file in a different way as app.config from test app is not app.config of tested app... Tests load even executable as assemblies and configuration implementation is searching in currentexecutable.exe.config.... So it's probably searching in vstest.exe.config

Comment: Sorry @Selvin not sure what you meant. I have take a snippet from  project that is even in live. Previously the file was referenced in the App.Config from shared location on a server. All now I need to do is include the file in the project and provide the path to the file in the App.Config.  As I mentioned the file is the in the root directory of the project

Comment: It doesn't matter.. What maters is how configuration implementation works... Is not that BaseBindings.xml could not be found but there is no BaseBindings.xml in  used app.config at all

Comment: The c# code is reading the config section to load the BaseBindings.xml file. Since the path is incorrect its is not able to read the file

Comment: Open Properties window for BaseBindings.xml file. Set Copy to Output Directory value to Copy if newer or Copy always. Enjoy.

Comment: Hmm I have done that actually. My question was more related to setting the path in the app.config. If you see there is key called default file which is read within the code. I need to specify the path of the file in the value field. Am I right or is that not required

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that `BaseBindings.xml` is copied to the output directory?
Ensure that you have this in your `SITTest.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="BaseBindings.xml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, from Solution Explorer, right-click on "BaseBindings.xml" and then choose "Properties".

Set the **Build Action** to "Content" and **Copy to Output Directory** to either "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer".

Then you can read the content of the file in code, like below:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(@"BaseBindings.xml");
string bindings = reader.ReadLine();
```

If your question is about setting the filepath in the app.config, you can just do as follows:

```
<add key="defaultFile" value="BaseBindings.xml" />
```

Then;

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultFile"];
var reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(filePath));
string bindings = reader.ReadLine();
```

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To refer to an XML file (in your case, `BaseBindings.xml`) from your `app.config` file in a C# application, you should provide the correct relative path based on the location of the `app.config` file and the location of the XML file within your project structure.

Assuming your project structure is as shown in your provided image, and you want to access `BaseBindings.xml` from your `app.config`, you should use a relative path like this:

```xml
<add key="defaultFile" value="BaseBindings.xml" />
```

In this case, the `BaseBindings.xml` file is in the same directory as your `app.config` file, so you can reference it directly without any path components like `.\` or `..`. This relative path assumes that the XML file is in the same directory as the `app.config` file.

Make sure that the XML file's "Copy to Output Directory" property is set to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always" to ensure that it's copied to the output directory when you build your project.